# Are drill down, roll up, slice and dice, pivot supported by MDX query language?

Tags: mdx, olap, multidimensional-array, drilldown, rollup

I read some resources regarding multidimensional operation (roll up, drill down, slice, dice and pivot) and MDX query language for my project.
I know there are several standards in OLAP query.

Are drill down, roll up, slice and dice, pivot supported by MDX query languange?
Or is it totally two different methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; by nature MDX is handling all these operations: for example drill-down, roll up  are  performed when asking members (i.e., parents vs children) along a hierarchy. Or you can explicitly use several Drilldown functions. The [WHERE](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Where%20Clause.html) statement is slicing the cube. Etc...

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! So I get your point that it is not semantically supported by MDX, rather it is supported technically, am I right?
Therefore, if I have a statement for example "ROLLUP ON [Dimension_Name]", it has to be translated into appropriate MDX form.